# How to add company logo to the merged cell of table?

Tags: tables, graphics, overleaf, logos, cell

I am making a CV and in experiences section, I would like to have a logo (normally a small image) before the designation and the company name. This logo must be in the merged cell of first raw second collum(R1C2) and second raw second colum(R2C2) as shoun in the example pic below:

[image]

Where the designation and Company name and location will be left aligned next to the logo. Also the Description of the experience,  tec1, tech2, tech3, will be moved to left.

Following is the latex code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}

%New length definition
\newlength{\rightcolumnlength}
\setlength{\rightcolumnlength}{14.8cm}

\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

% underline-color set-up: General
\newcommand{\blueuline}[1]{{\color{textcolor}\uline{{\color{black}#1}}}}

% Usage;\myhyperlink{<url>}{<text or words>}
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[2]{\blueuline{\href{#1}{\itshape{#2}}}}

% Usage: \cvtag{<tag label>}
\newcommand{\cvtag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=black!70,rounded corners=0.5ex,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.55ex,text height=1.3ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

% command experience
\newcommand\experience[8]
{
  \textbf{#1}    & \textbf{#2}     \\*
  \textbf{#3}    & #4,\textbf{#5}  \\*
                 & #6              \\*
                 & \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolumnlength}  
                             #7                                 
                    \end{minipage}  \\*
                 & \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#8}{\cvtag{\n}}} \\
}

\begin{document}

\section{Experiences}

\begin{longtable}{R|E}
  \experience
    {Feb 2022}   {Software Developer}
    {Jan 2018}{\myhyperlink{https:www.example.com}{Company}}{ Place, Country}
    {Description ....}
    {
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Responsibility at the company.
            \item Responsibility at the company.
            \item Responsibility at the company.
            \item Responsibility at the company.
          \end{itemize}
    }
    {tec1, tec2, tec3, etc}
    
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Note that, in the above table I am missing the middle colum, which I am not sure how should be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¸Like this?

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)

Changes in your MWE is indicated by `% <---`<.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, multirow}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}

%New length definition
\newlength{\rightcolumnlength}
\setlength{\rightcolumnlength}{97mm}            % <---

\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

% underline-color set-up: General
\newcommand{\blueuline}[1]{{\color{textcolor}\uline{{\color{black}#1}}}}

% Usage;\myhyperlink{<url>}{<text or words>}
\newcommand{\myhyperlink}[2]{\blueuline{\href{#1}{\itshape{#2}}}}

% Usage: \cvtag{<tag label>}
\newcommand{\cvtag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=black!70,rounded corners=0.5ex,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.55ex,text height=1.3ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

% command experience
\newcommand\experience[9]                       % <---
{
\textbf{#1} & \multirow[b]{2}[3]{*}{#2}         % <---
                    &   \textbf{#3}     \\*
\textbf{#4} &       & #5,\newline               % <---
                      \textbf{#6}       \\*
            &       & #7                \\*
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolumnlength}
                    #8
                \end{minipage}}         \\*
            &       & \footnotesize{\foreach \n in {#9}{\cvtag{\n}}} \\
}

\begin{document}

\section{Experiences}

\begin{longtable}{r|p{0.5\rightcolumnlength} @{}        % <---
                    p{0.5\rightcolumnlength}}           % <---
\experience
    {Feb 2022}
    {\includegraphics[height=9mm]{example-image-duck}}  % <---
    {Software Developer}
    %
    {Jan 2018}
    {\myhyperlink{https:www.example.com}{Company name}}
    { Place, Country}
    %
    {Description ....}
    %
    { \begin{itemize}
        \item Responsibility at the company.
        \item Responsibility at the company.
              Responsibility at the company.
              Responsibility at the company.
        \item Responsibility at the company.
        \item Responsibility at the company.
      \end{itemize}
    }
    %
    {tec1, tec2, tec3, etc}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not qite what I want. However, I could extend the idea of `{r|p{0.5\rightcolumnlength} @{}  p{0.5\rightcolumnlength}}` to my case and it has been solved nicely. Thanks for the help.